# R script schedulling

Tags: r, scheduler, k-means

I have created an R script that runs a K-means segmentation for one of my customers. How can I run this script every thirty days? The script should be on Linux Server.

Comment: Set up a cronjob on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Sys.sleep` to suspend execution for a given number of seconds. You could use this combined with a `while` to execute a function that runs your K-means segmentation.

I would however recommend you use a task scheduler for this, cron in your case. Just use `Rscript` to run your script as a cronjob. This does not require an R process to remain active, will launch on restart of the machine, and is easier to stop (no need to kill the process).

Comment: I edited my answer to use cron. In addition, you are right in your assumption. My answer already refers to this in stating the advantages of using a task scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to create an `R` script for your k-means calculation.  Save this file as `your_script.R`.
2. Next create a Windows batch file `your_batch.bat` which will execute the `R` script.  The batch file should contain the following line which uses `Rscript` to launch `R`:

   `Rscript your_script.R arg1 arg2`
3. Finally you can use the Windows **Task Scheduler** to setup your script to run every 30 days.  Do a Windows search for "Task Scheduler" to find it, and specify `your_batch.bat` as the program to run.

Comment: The OP specified (after you posted your answer) that the script will be run on Linux. This answer is Windows-specific.